# MessagePack how to write a stream of serialized structs to / from a BufWriter/BufReader

Tags: rust, serde, msgpack

I'm writing a giant stream of messages (from a websocket feed) to a file.

The messages look like this, an enum of structs that are themselves serializable.

```
enum SerializedMessage {
    Level2(Level2),
    Full(Full),
    Match(Match),
    BookL3(Book<BookRecordL3>)
}
```

For example:

```
let output_msg = SerializedMessage::BookL3(book);
rmp_serde::Serializer::new(writer_buf.get_mut())).unwrap();
```

This seems to work, but I can't get deserialization to work past the first message:

```
    let  reader_buf =  &mut BufReader::new(file);

    let msg1 : SerializedMessage = rmp_serde::decode::from_read(reader_buf.get_mut()).unwrap();
    dbg!(msg1); /// WORKS!

    let msg2 : SerializedMessage = rmp_serde::decode::from_read(reader_buf.get_mut()).unwrap();
    dbg!(msg2); /// FAILS
```

msg1 displays ok, but by msg2 I get:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Syntax("invalid type: unit value, expected a string")', src/main.rs:313:87**
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need a framing protocol on top of messagepack messages. Currently, the code may consume the whole BufReader on the `msg1` decode, or have other unexpected side-effects.

You could for example prefix each packet with a data-length, and then continue parsing frames by first checking the packet length, taking length-sized bytes, and repeating the process as long as the source has more bytes.

For inspiration, see https://docs.rs/tokio-util/latest/tokio_util/codec/index.html, https://github.com/volks73/framed-msgpack and https://crates.io/crates/nom